# Text Fields and Buttons Merge to top When Run Android project

Tags: android-layout

This is My Simple Project GUI Interface

[My Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Xwk.png)

When I run It Its Look Like This

[On Run Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fHfM.png)

How Can I fix this problem ?

Comment: use LinearLayout with vertical orientation.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearanceRegular.FontPath" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
         android:hint="number1"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
         android:hint="number2"
        android:textSize="16sp" />



 <Button 
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:text="+"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```